# Never used Variable Optimisation

Tags: c#, performance, compilation

Im not shure if this has been asked bevore. I could not find it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new ExampleClass();
        ExampleClass example = new ExampleClass();
    }
}
class ExampleClass
{
    public ExampleClass()
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

is the first initialization faster? Dose the second one get Optimised at compile time. (Asuming the varaible example is never used)

Comment: What would be the usefulness of the first line?

Comment: I'd say the easiest way to figure this out would be to compile with optimizations then inspec the IL code (or use a decomipiler).

Comment: *"At compile time"* - inlikely. At run-time for sure, static initialization was done already.

Comment: But it could be Optimised right?

Comment: What are you trying to optimize?

Comment: @xxbbcc the space required for the "example" variable

Comment: Where do you think your `Example` instance would be? The variable is _not the storage space_, it's just a _name for the storage space_. Your instance still needs to live somewhere. When you create something, it uses memory until you get rid of it.

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto it Might not be good programing but you could do stuff in the constructor.Sorta use it as Method then.

Comment: @xxbbcc well you could theoreticaly refrence the ExampleClass object with the "example" variable. Wich means it needs space. But if its never used you could also not create the refrence. And sota optimise it at compile time.

Comment: If variable is not used, then compiler may not even introduce it and GC may collect the instance. Unless there are strong references, etc. This is implementation details. You shouldn't rely on it and it's not clear how you going to use this information or which problem you have.

Comment: If a constructor has side effects, then it's really bad programming.

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto Yes but the question is about weather of not the unused refrence would be optimised by the compiler.

Comment: `Might not be good programing but you could do stuff in the constructor.Sorta use it as Method then`. Why debating the possible performance optimizations/impacts/benefits/disadvantages of horrible programming practices. Even when debating this out of curiosity, what would be the "take-away point" of such a discussion? I mean, what else besides "whatever the performance impact, this amounts to horrible practice. Don't do that!"...?

Comment: @elgonzo well the point is only curiosity. If thats not ok and these kinds of questions should not be asked. Then ok. Ill remove the question then.

Comment: @ChrisFraser, i did not say it is not okay to ask such a question (if that were the case, i would have downvoted your question). But it is in my eyes a somewhat poor question for SO, as the answer to that is not of much use to a software developer (because "bad practice"). If you are interested in how the C# and .NET JIT compilers operate with regard to allowed (or disallowed) optimizations in certain normal (or unnormal) circumstances, questions like yours are probably better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com. (i should have better referred to SE in my previous comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the first initialization faster?

Not in any remotely significant way, so why even care? But, just to humor you, the IL output of both options, when compiled with optimizations on, is the same:

```
// Methods
.method private hidebysig static 
    void Main (
        string[] args
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 7 (0x7)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: newobj instance void ExampleClass::.ctor()
    IL_0005: pop
    IL_0006: ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

So no, there is no difference.

> Asuming the varaible example is never used

Why are you instantiating an object you are never going to use? If what you are trying to achieve is simply running some initializing logic then implement an aptly named static method:

```
class ExampleClass
{
     static void Initialize() { // do stuff }
}
```

And you'd call it in a less disconcerting manner:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ExampleClass.Initialize();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is not relevant what the Compiler does in this scenario.

Indeed, there is no doubt in both cases the code in the ExampleClass constructor would be executed.
It may be the Compiler does optimize memory use in this very specific (and rather simple) scenario, however if the variable is never used then why creating a new instance of ExampleClass? You may prefer a utility method or helper (maybe static).

In general, you use objects to better handle and represent your data, keep references and benefit by useful development styles and design patterns such as [Dependency Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323705(v=vs.100).aspx).

Otherwise, it may be enough to just use a method or a static helper.